# Does postgres optimizes repeated expression in select query?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I'm using jooq to generate SQL query and I'm a bit lazy to generate nested select from another_select from bottom_select. My generated query contains repeated expressions. Does postgres 13+ applies some optimisation techniques under the hood?

simplified sample part of query

```sql
SELECT
case
           when b.count is null then 100.00
           when c.count is null then -100.00
           else round(
                   cast((100.00 * ((c.count - b.count) / cast(b.count as numeric))) as numeric),
                   2
               )
           end as expression_01,

case
           when b.count is null then 100.00
           when c.count is null then -100.00
           else round(
                   cast((100.00 * ((c.count - b.count) / cast(b.count as numeric))) as numeric),
                   2
               )
           end as expression_02
from some_table
```

let's say

```sql
round(
                   cast((100.00 * ((c.count - b.count) / cast(b.count as numeric))) as numeric),
                   2
               )
```

was repeated multiple times, will Postgres calculate it once or many times?

Comment: Even if it's calculated each time it occurs in the SELECT list, the cost will be negligible compared with the other costs of the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, PostgreSQL has no such optimization and will calculate the expression multiple times. If the query is expensive enough and you have JIT enabled, it may create custom executable code for the expressions to speed up processing, but it is still executed twice.

Comment: thanks, will push it down to sub-query to calculate once and reuse values in higher level selects